# Fetching correct news image - JAVA

Tags: java, image, web-scraping, web-crawler, image-size

I am trying to make a small news crawler.
I got every thing working after many tries.

Problem is that approx every HTML news page have more then 50 images.

Many of them are too small. So, i am filtering them simply by checking size.
Only images lager them 200x200 will be taken.

But there are many images on a single page which are large.
and some news articles not have any related image.

Lets take a example -
Link to News -  http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/Over-9-3-lakh-TB-patients-in-India-undetected-Report/articleshow/24600851.cms

My code got this image - Image no. 0 http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/10905539.cms
Image height - 300
Image width - 450

But this image is useless to image topic.
In simple words "How to get correct image dynamically"

I do not want to make code for each website.
A blank image is better then a wrong image.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `alt` text. The `alt` text usually contains either the title completely or some words from the title.

Also, the article does not have any relevant image associated with the title.

I also suggest [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/):

> jsoup: Java HTML Parser
>
> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides
>   a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the
>   best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.
>
> jsoup implements the WHATWG HTML5 specification, and parses HTML to
>   the same DOM as modern browsers do.
>
> ```
> scrape and parse HTML from a URL, file, or string
> find and extract data, using DOM traversal or CSS selectors
> manipulate the HTML elements, attributes, and text
> clean user-submitted content against a safe white-list, to prevent XSS attacks
> output tidy HTML
> ```

Comment: alt tag mostly time is absent and i posted this link just for example. My code is a dynamic news parser which works auto.

Comment: Now that is a serious accessibility bug , isn't it ? Also it makes work harder for the developer. I think what `Anantha Sharma` said is also a good approach but chances are you will be fetching images of other articles in the recommendations section

Comment: Also, most newspapers have their `API`s. Does Times of India have an API ?

Comment: You are right, but again API is a specific thing, I am taking about a handful of websites

Comment: Well, all major newspapers have APIs. =) http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/01/09/how-many-newspapers-have-an-api/

Comment: Thanks for the link. but again not what i am doing. i am trying to make my own, which is any API independent

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40026/discussion-between-lovepreet-singh-batth-and-little-child)

Comment: Well, I am not qualified enough to continue the discussion in chat =)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an approach where you identify the proximity of an image based on its position.. so, if an Image comes inside the article its probably an image about the article itself (except for ads which are very wide).

you can findout the source of the image and decide if it should interest you or not. for instance ad images usually come from a different server which doesn't belong to the site. (in your case indiatimes.com).

Comment: Please check again images is from same source is example and your approach is good, but it is only possible for a single website, i am trying to code a dynamic parser